# I am logged into mysql as root but cannot grant extra privileges to users

Tags: mysql, linux, privileges, database-replication

I am logged into mysql as the root user and trying to setup MYSQL Replication. I have already setup my database as a Master but when I try the 'show master status;' command its saying:

ERROR 1227 (42000): Access denied; you need the SUPER,REPLICATION CLIENT privile
ge for this operation

When I try and add these privileges to the root user I am getting:

ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'%' (using password: YES)

Im lost as to what I can do at this point.

Any help would be greatly appreciated,

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you sure you have the right root password?

Comment: which interface are you using to manage privileges?

Comment: I definately have the correct password as I am logging into mysql with it! I am logging into the mysql prompt through ssh.

Answer (score 0):

It might be necessary that you have to be on localhost, not on a remote machine.

Comment: My server is London based so therefore I only have access to it remotely through ssh. Is there any other solution to this?

Comment: Thats the problem though, I can't add privileges to users using the root user as I keep getting denied!

Comment: I just tried this and it didnt work either:
1.Stop mysqld and restart it with the --skip-grant-tables option. 
2.Connect to the mysqld server with just: mysql (i.e. no -p option, and username may not be required).
3.Issue the following commands in the mysql client:

UPDATE mysql.user SET Grant_priv='Y', Super_priv='Y' WHERE User='root';

Comment: From which machine to you connect? What host name are you using? 127.0.0.1 or localhost? A search for Mysql 127.0.0.1 problems might help

Comment: jbreval, thanks for pointing me to the command to add the Grant_priv.  I stupidly locked myself out of sql by somehow revoking the Grant privilege on all my accounts, I was able to start mysql with skip-grant-tables but of course then the GRANT commands would not work.  Modifying the mysql.user table did the trick.  Thanks!